# Symbol not found: _iconv libiconv.2.dylib

Tags: php

When I try to run VBoxManage, I get the following error. I also get it if I try to run php by itself. Any idea what to do to fix it?

```
$ VBoxManage --help
dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
in /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Comment: Have you tried installing (lib)iconv?